# Unable to upgrade pip using pip install --upgrade pip

Tags: pip

I wanted to upgrade pip for installing libraries to learn machine learning. But i am unable to do so.

```
C:\Users\adith>pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-21.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 211 kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 20.2.3
    Uninstalling pip-20.2.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.3
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\adith\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-40mydp3z\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.
```

I am getting the above error. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Could+not+install+packages+due+to+an+EnvironmentError%3A+WinError+5+Access+is+denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There are two ways to go about this:

#### * *(Recommended way)* is to just append the `--user` flag to the command you are trying to run, so you would run `pip install --upgrade pip --user`

or

#### * open cmd as an administrator and run that command

..................................................................................................................................

The reason this happened is because the folder you are trying to install pip is a folder that requires admin privileges to access.

```
Next time you should pay attention to what the error message says.
Most of the time the error message is self explanitory and there is no need to post a new question on S.O.
```

Comment: thnx a bunch... it worked... my bad i didnt notice...